# Read integer from user method

Tags: java

Is there any method in java that reads and returns an integer value from the user and if the user types a value that is not a legal integer, the method offers the user a chance to re-enter the data again.
I am looking for something similar to readInt() in IOConsole Class in the ACM Documentations.

thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Sure...the method you're about to create will do exactly that function.

Answer (score 4):

You can read the value as string, and then use `NumberUtils.isNumber(..)` (from commons-lang), or `Integer.parseInt(str)` and catch the exception. If the value is not a proper integer, read again. You can use the `java.io.Console#readLine()` or `java.util.Scanner#next()`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use it like this:

```
 String S_number = JLable1.getText();
 int I_number = Integer.parseInt(S_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read form a console remember to:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

To determine if a certain value is or is not an integer you can use this simple function:

```
public static boolean isInteger(String str){
try { 
    Integer.parseInt(str); 
} catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
    return false; 
}
return true;
}
```

Then, to check, use:

```
String value = new String("");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

// Reads a single line from the console and stores into value variable
value = in.nextLine();

if (isInteger(value)){
System.out.println("It is an integer");
} else {
System.out.println("It's not an integer");
}
```